# access by index to object value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please consider the 3 following variables :

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({ serverInfo: '', username: '', password: '' });
const [showAlert, setShowAlert] = useState({ serverInfo: false, username: false, password: false });
const [alertText, setAlertText] = useState({ serverInfo: '', username: '', password: '' });
```

I am dynamically rendering some components by mapping `items`:

```
const items = [
    { label: 'Nom d\'utilisateur', name: 'username', type: 'text', value: values.username },
    { label: 'Mot de passe', name: 'password', type: 'password', value: values.password }
]

//.........

{items.map((element, idx) => (
    <FormGroup key={idx} className="mb-3">
    <FloatingLabel key={idx} label={element.label}>
        <Form.Control key={idx} type={element.type} name={element.name} placeholder={element.name} onChange={handleChange} value={element.value} />
    </FloatingLabel>
    {showAlert[idx + 1] && <Alert key={idx} className='mb-1' variant="warning" >
        {alertText[idx + 1]}
    </Alert>}
    </FormGroup>
))}
```

I think you guessed what I am trying to do, but unfortunetely, `showAlert[1] != showAlert.username`.

Is there a convinient way to reach this behavior ? Thank you.

Comment: `showAlert` is not an array, it's an object in your code. Also the `key` prop is only needed on the outermost child in a map, in this case `FormGroup`.

Comment: I think the keyword `object` answers the question then... it looks like it is impossible to access by index...

Comment: I haven't guessed what you're trying to do. Do you mean `showAlert[element.name]`?

Comment: @pilchard this actually solves the problem, well... thank you.